# Elements in my array are storing incorrect values even after user is being prompted

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to create a score storing program where I ask a user for scores to store in an array and just print them out at the end of it. However, when I tried to do that, the values of the array are being changed to 32764, 4198754 etc.

My code:

```
int main (void){
    int score;
    //int sum = 0;
    int num_score = get_int("Enter the number of scores: ");
    int scores[num_score]; 
    printf("Enter Scores below\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_score; i++){
        score = get_int("Score %i: " ,i); 
        score = scores[i]; 
        }
        printf("The scores are as follows: \n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= num_score; i++ ){
        //sum = sum + scores[i];
        printf("Score %i = %i\n",i,scores[i]);
        }
```

For example, if there are a total of 3 scores, and the user enters score 1 = 78, score 2 = 67 and score 3 = 83
The expected output should be:

```
Score 1 = 78
Score 2 = 67
Score 3 = 83
```

Instead, the values that were printed out are as follows:

```
Score 1 = 32767
Score 2 = 4198754
Score 3 = 0
```

Why is this so? I'd like to understand see where I went wrong.

Comment: `score = scores[i];` looks backwards.

Comment: Note that the array indexing will break the bounds. In C arrays are indexed from 0 so `for (int i = 1; i <= num_score; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < num_score; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misused the assignment operator here:

```c
score = scores[i];
```

The assignment operator sets the value of *lefthand operand* to the value of *righthand operand*.

It should be:

```c
scores[i] = score;
```

Also the array declaration

```c
int scores[num_score];
```

should be

```c
int scores[num_score+1];
```

To enable usage of `scores[num_score]`.